# How to draw the Mean Value Theorem graphic with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

(Edited 2014-03-23) Can anyone give a TikZ solution to my question?

I want to add an illustration of the Mean Value Theorem (Lagrange) like this:
[image]

```
\begin{center}
{\Huge \shadowbox{\textbf{Teorema del Valor Medio (Lagrange)}}}
\end{center}

\[\frac{{f(b) - f(a)}}{{b - a}} = f'(c)\]
```

Basically, I need the axis with the x and y labels, the function, the secant, the tangent and something that is missing in the picture: f(a), f(b) and f(c).

I made the picture that I want to make with TikZ with GeoGebra:
[image]

Comment: Also did you search the site?         http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=tangent+curve Especially http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99086/3235

Comment: Any solutions with TikZ?

Comment: Without any try yourself at all, don't expect any.

Comment: Of course I'm trying. But this site is for sharing knowledge and if someone has the answer before, what's wrong about asking? And supose I do not want to work, your answer will serve not only for me, it will be available for the entire world.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me; I'm not trying to offend you. I' just saying that your should give it a try yourself; post whatever code you have got so far. (If the question has been answered before, you can find the answer by searching the page.)

Answer (score 8):

My try with MetaPost, mostly for fun since there are already very fine solutions above. The main macro, `find_all_direction_points`, based on the `directiontime` MetaPost macro, theoretically returns every point whose tangents share the same direction, and the number of these points.

The following LaTeX code uses the `gmp` package as interface for Metapost and is to be typeset with the shell-escape option activated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latex, shellescape]{gmp}
  \gmpoptions{everymp={input latexmp; 
    setupLaTeXMP(options="12pt", textextlabel=enable, mode=rerun);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost*}[mpmem=metafun]
  % Macro that finds all points of p where the tangents share the same direction v
  vardef find_all_direction_points(expr p, v)(suffix C, n) =
    save s, q; path q; q = p;
    n:= 0; 
    s = directiontime v of p; 
    forever:
      exitunless s<>-1; 
      n := n+1;
      C[n] := point s of q;
      q := subpath(s+epsilon, infinity) of q;
      s := directiontime v of q;
    endfor;
  enddef;
  % Axes, graph, tangents and secant definitions
  u := 2cm; xmin := -0.5; xmax := 6; ymin := -0.5; ymax := 4.5;
  pair A, B, C; A = (1, 3); B = (5, 1); 
  pair C[], v; 
  v = unitvector(B-A);
  path p, secant; p = A{dir 70} ..  B{dir 60}; secant = A--B;
  find_all_direction_points(p, B-A)(C,n);
  % Function graph, and secant
  draw p scaled u ;
  draw secant scaled u withcolor red;
  % Tangent drawing
  for k= 1 upto n:
    draw (C[k]-v -- C[k] + v) scaled u withcolor green;
    draw C[k] scaled u withpen pencircle scaled 3bp;
  endfor;
  % axes and locations
  drawarrow (xmin*u, 0) -- (xmax*u, 0) ;
  drawarrow (0, ymin*u) -- (0, ymax*u) ;
  for M = A, B, C1:
    draw (u*xpart M, 0) -- u*M -- (0, u*ypart M) dashed evenly;
  endfor;
  % Labels
  label.bot("$a$", (u*xpart A, 0)); label.bot("$b$", (u*xpart B, 0)); 
  label.bot("$c$", (u*xpart C1, 0)); label.bot("$x$", (xmax*u, 0));
  label.lft("$f(a)$", (0, u*ypart A)); label.lft("$f(b)$", (0, u*ypart B)); 
  label.lft("$f(c)$", (0, u*ypart C1)); label.lft("$y$", (0, ymax*u));
  label.top("Tangent at $c$", C1*u) rotatedaround (C1*u, angle(B-A));
  label.bot("Secant", u*0.4[A,B]) rotatedaround (u*0.4[A,B], angle(B-A));
  label.bot("Another tangent", C2*u) rotatedaround (C2*u, angle(B-A));
  tN := 0.45; pair N; N = point tN along p;
  label.top("$y=f(x)$", u*N) rotatedaround(u*N, angle(direction tN of p));
\end{mpost*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\Function[1]{\fpeval{(-3*(#1)^3+45*(#1)^2-189*(#1))/65+7}}
\newcommand*\ParallelPoint{\fpeval{5+sqrt(7)}}                         % need to calculate yourself
\newcommand*\ParallelTangent[1]{\fpeval{(-27*(#1)+395+42*sqrt(7))/65}} % need to calculate yourself
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,-0.4)(10.9,5.9)
{\psset{linestyle = dashed}
  \psline[linecolor = blue](1,\Function{1})(0,\Function{1})
  \psline[linecolor = blue](10,\Function{10})(0,\Function{10})
  \psline[linecolor = orange](1,0)(1,\Function{1})
  \psline[linecolor = orange](10,\Function{10})(10,0)
  \psline[linecolor = green!60](10,\ParallelTangent{10})(10,\Function{10})
  \psline[linecolor = green!60](\ParallelPoint,0)(\ParallelPoint,\Function{\ParallelPoint})(0,\Function{\ParallelPoint})}
  \psline[linecolor = orange]{->}(1,\Function{1})(10,\Function{10})
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = -9pt](1,\Function{1})(10,\Function{10})
  \ncput[nrot = :U]{Secant}
  \psline[linecolor = green!60]{->}(5,\ParallelTangent{5})(10,\ParallelTangent{10})
  \psaxes[labels = none, ticks = none]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-0.2)(10.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
  \psplot[algebraic, linecolor = blue]{1}{10}{(-3*x^3+45*x^2-189*x)/65+7}
  \psdots(1,\Function{1})(10,\Function{10})
  \uput[270](3,\Function{3}){$y = f(x)$}
  \uput[180](5,\ParallelTangent{5}){Tangent at $c$}
  \uput[270](1,0){$a$}
  \uput[150](0,\Function{1}){$f(a)$}
  \uput[270](\ParallelPoint,0){$c$}
  \uput[210](0,\Function{\ParallelPoint}){$f(c)$}
  \uput[270](10,0){$b$}
  \uput[180](0,\Function{10}){$f(b)$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Nice output, but there is a lot of hardcoding in the input... Can it be reduced?

Comment: @Jubobs See updated answer. Do you think it can be improved further?

Comment: Difficult to say, since I don't know PStricks, but it looks much better `:)`

Answer (score 7):

With a new method in which the abscissa `c` is automatically determined without having to evaluate derivative of `f(x)` by hand. Is it nice?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pstricks-add}

\def\f(#1){((#1)*(#1-5)*(#1-6)/4+1.5*(#1)-5)}
\def\m(#1,#2){(\f(#2)-\f(#1))/(#2-#1)}
\def\fp(#1){Derive(1,\f(#1))}% f'(x) 

\def\L#1{\uput[-90](#1|0,0){$#1\mathstrut$}\uput[180](0,0|#1){$f(#1)$}\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](#1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[algebraic,saveNodeCoors,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none](-1,-1)(8,8)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(7.5,7.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \pstGeonode(*1 {\f(x)}){a}(*6.5 {\f(x)}){b}
    \makeatletter\pst@Verb{/ax N-a.x def /bx N-b.x def}\makeatother
    \psplot[linecolor=blue]{ax}{bx}{\f(x)}
    \pstInterFF{\m(ax,bx)}{\fp(x)}{4}{temp}
    \pstGeonode(*N-temp.x {\f(x)}){c}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1,linecolor=green](a)(b)
    \psxline[linecolor=red](c){.1(a)-.1(b)}{.1(b)-.1(a)}
    \psset{linecolor=gray,linestyle=dashed}
    \foreach \i in {a,b,c}{\L{\i}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what???.. you put in the `5.3` by hand for the `c` location? you lower your standards compared to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167238/how-to-modify-pstinterff-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-a-constant-m-an ;-)

Comment: ah! that was earlier! sorry you have *increased* your standards, great job  `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu: (-: and :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a figure from my calculus lecture notes:

```
\documentclass[preview,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{point/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\newcommand{\thescale}{0.5}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{one choice for $x_0$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\thescale*1.2]
    \draw[thick] (1,1) node[point,fill=black] (a) {} parabola bend (3,3) (4,2.5) node[point,fill=black] (b) {};
    \draw[thick] (1,1) -- (4,2.5);
    \draw (1,1+9/8) -- (4,2.5+9/8) coordinate (topright);
    \node[point,fill=black] (x0) at (2.5,2.875) {};

    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \draw[<->] (topright -| origin) -- (origin) -- (origin -| topright) -- +(1,0);
    \draw[dotted,very thick] (a) -- (a|-origin) node[below,black] {$a$};
    \draw[dotted,very thick] (b) -- (b|-origin) node[below] {$b$};
    \draw[dashed] (x0) -- (x0|-origin) node[below] {$x_0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{two choices for $x_0$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\thescale]
    \begin{scope}
    \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw[thick,smooth,domain=-3:3] plot (\x,{\x^3/3 - \x});
    \end{scope}
    \node[point,fill=black] (a) at (-2,-2/3) {};
    \node[point,fill=black] (b) at (2,2/3) {};
    \draw[thick] (a) -- (b);
    \coordinate (origin) at (-4,-3);
    \coordinate (topright) at (4,2);
    \draw[<->] (topright -| origin) -- (origin) -- (origin -| topright);
    \draw[dotted,very thick] (a) -- (a|-origin) node[below] {$a$};
    \draw[dotted,very thick] (b) -- (b|-origin) node[below] {$b$};

    \node[point,fill=black] (x0) at ({-2/sqrt(3)},{(1/3)*(-2/sqrt(3))^3+2/sqrt(3)}) {};
    \draw (x0) +(-1,-1/3) -- +(1,1/3);
    \node[point,fill=black] (x1) at ({2/sqrt(3)},{(1/3)*(2/sqrt(3))^3-2/sqrt(3)}) {};
    \draw (x1) +(-1,-1/3) -- +(1,1/3);
    \draw[dashed] (x0) -- (x0 |- origin) node[below]{$x_0$};
    \draw[dashed] (x1) -- (x1 |- origin) node[below]{$x_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{\centering infinitely many choices for $x_0$}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\thescale/1.2]
    \draw[thick,smooth] plot coordinates{(-2,-1) (-1.75,0) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,4.74) (4,5)} ++(1,0) coordinate (topright);
    \coordinate (origin) at (-3,-2);
    \draw[<->] (origin|-topright) -- (origin) -- (origin-|topright);
    \node[point,fill=black] (a) at (-2,-1) {};
    \node[point,fill=black] (b) at (4,5) {};

    \draw[very thick, dotted] (a) -- (a|-origin) node[below] {$a$};
    \draw[dotted,very thick] (b) -- (b|-origin) node[below] {$b$};

    \draw[thin] (-2,0) -- (4,6);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,2) -- (1,3);

    \draw[dashed] (0,2) -- (0,-2);
    \draw[dashed] (0.5,2.5) -- (0.5,-2);
    \draw[dashed] (1,3) -- (1,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Is this a hack? It feels like a hack...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \path ( 1,4)        node[coordinate] (a1) {}
        (10,5)        node[coordinate] (b1) {}
        (a1) ++(0,-2) node[coordinate] (a2) {}
        (b1) ++(0,-2) node[coordinate] (b2) {};

  \path[draw,green] (a1) -- (b1);

  \path[draw,red] (a2) --
    node[coordinate,pos=0.05] (c1) {}
    node[coordinate,pos=0.2 ] (c2) {}
    node[coordinate,pos=0.4 ] (c3) {}
    (b2);

  \draw[densely dashed] (a1)
    .. controls +(0,0) and  (c1)   .. (c2)
    .. controls  (c3)  and +(-2,2) .. (b1);

  \foreach \point/\text in {a1/a , b1/b , c2/c}
    \draw[dotted]
        let \p1 = (\point)
      in
           (0  ,\y1) node[anchor=east ] {$f(\text)$}
        -- (\p1)
        -- (\x1,0  ) node[anchor=north] {$\text$};

  \draw[->] (-1.5, 0  ) -- (11,0  ) node[anchor=south east] {\textsf{x}};
  \draw[->] (   0,-1.5) -- ( 0,6.5) node[anchor=north west] {\textsf{y}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works by making use of control points. From the manual:

> One or two "control points" are needed. The math behind them is not quite trivial, but here is the basic idea: Suppose you are at point x and the first control point is y. Then the curve will start "going in the direction of y at x," that is, *the tangent of the curve at x will point toward y*.
>   (Section 2.4, Emphasis added)

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's not really a hack; TikZ has no convenient method for computing the tangent line to a path, so almost any TikZ solution involves constructing the path in such a way that you know its tangent at the point in question. I did this by using a formula for the curve and differentiating it by hand, which is less flexible than what you have here.

Comment: Incidentally, in the `\foreach` loop, you want `c2/c` rather than `c1/c`.

Comment: Well spotted. Fixed!